# Why is git clone asking incorrect user name for my repository account?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to 'pip install' a piece of software from my company's internal repository, so I created a repository for the project on gitlab. Then I tried to execute:

```
pip3 install git+ssh://git.intra.mycompany.com/unlp/normalizer.git
```

My user name on the repository is @congmin. But when the above command is executed, the following shows up:

```
Collecting git+ssh://git.intra.mycompany.com/unlp/normalizer.git
  Cloning ssh://git.intra.mycompany.com/unlp/normalizer.git to /private/var/folders/g3/t6sb30rj2z7_4dqy84l5jbhr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-0ue6j8ob
  Running command git clone -q ssh://git.intra.weibo.com/unlp/normalizer.git /private/var/folders/g3/t6sb30rj2z7_4dqy84l5jbhr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-0ue6j8ob
congminmin@git.intra.mycompany.com's password:
```

Then I type my password on the repository, but it is always wrong. I think the reason is that somehow 'congminmin', instead of 'congmin' was considered as my username, as can be seen from the above message. Then I tried this url with my correct username:

```
pip3 install git+ssh://git.intra.mycompany.com:congmin/unlp/normalizer.git
```

But this immediately gave me the error:

```
Collecting git+ssh://git.intra.mycompany.com:congmin/unlp/normalizer.git
  Cloning ssh://git.intra.mycompany.com:congmin/unlp/normalizer.git to /private/var/folders/g3/t6sb30rj2z7_4dqy84l5jbhr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-9rasjeb_
  Running command git clone -q ssh://git.intra.mycompany.com:congmin/unlp/normalizer.git /private/var/folders/g3/t6sb30rj2z7_4dqy84l5jbhr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-9rasjeb_
  ssh: Could not resolve hostname git.intra.mycompany.com:congmin: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q ssh://git.intra.mycompany.com:congmin/unlp/normalizer.git /private/var/folders/g3/t6sb30rj2z7_4dqy84l5jbhr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-9rasjeb_ Check the logs for full command output.
```

Why is that? This is a very simple package, with only one python file and a few functions in it. I didn't create a setup.py for it. Could that be the reason? This is the first time I want to 'pip install from a git repository in my company'.

Comment: The syntax for specifying the user name is *usually* `user@address` not `address:user`.  So for normal git you'd use `ssh://congmin@git.intra.mycompany.com/`...  I would guess pip3 would be the same, but I've never really used it.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I tried the format you suggested, and it still says "Permission denied, please try again.". Maybe the pip install git+ssh ... format is incorrect? My purpose is to pip install a non-public repository.

Comment: `Permission Denied` usually means that you don't have your ssh keys set up properly.  Can you access the git repo directly, without using pip3?

Comment: Yes, I can. I can git push or pull without problems. I can also access it in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

For SSH, the user should be, even for a `git.intra.mycompany.com` on-premise Git repository hosting server, '`git`'

```
git+ssh://git@git.intra.mycompany.com/unlp/normalizer.git 
          ^^^
```

You should have registered a public key in that intranet Git repository hosting service, which will allow said service to authenticate you.
Such a service would not allow direct SSH session ("direct" as opened by you). It would allow only non-interactive session as '`git`'